# Large content in tableView Cells

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Do you know how can I display a large NSString on a tableView cell? Now it's showing only a part of the string, like: "This is a large string because...."

Do you know how can I display the entire information? In a wider cell? Is this possible?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the label to get as many lines as needed, use :

```
yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

You'll also need to set the cell with a sufficient size.
Note that you can get the size a string really needs by using this function:

```
CGSize expectedStringSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:self.font  /*the font that will be used in the label*/
                                    constrainedToSize:maximumSize /* The maximum width and height you want the label to take*/
                                    lineBreakMode:yourLineBreakMode/*UILineBreakModeHeadTruncation for example, not needed*/];
```

Comment: How can I apply that to the tableview's cell? A lot of thanks!

Comment: To get the size of a cell, the tableView launch heightForRowAtIndexPath for each line. So, you need to implement this function by returning the needed size here. Beware of performance problem, the function heightForRowAtIndexPath is called for ALL your rows, so you may have troubles if you have plenty of them.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the number of lines of your label :

```
yourLabel.numberOfLines = 2
```